# how is thread local storage via gcc __thread keyword implemented in x86_64?

Tags: gcc, ld, glibc, thread-local-storage

I'm digging around in libc and found an interesting asm sequence that I try to understand. `glibc-2.27/malloc/malloc.c` has:

```
 static __thread tcache_perthread_struct *tcache = NULL;
 ...
 # define MAYBE_INIT_TCACHE() \                                                                                                                                                 
      if (__glibc_unlikely (tcache == NULL)) \
 ....                                                                                                                                          
 void *                                                                                                                                                                         
 __libc_malloc (size_t bytes) {
 ...
    MAYBE_INIT_TCACHE()
```

gcc translates it to:

```
   96a97:       48 8b 2d da 42 35 00    mov    0x3542da(%rip),%rbp        # 3ead78 <.got+0x18>        
   ...     
   96aa6:       64 48 8b 4d 00          mov    %fs:0x0(%rbp),%rcx
```

in runtime `mov    0x3542da(%rip),%rbp`  will yield a negative value, i.e.:

```
(gdb) p $rbp
$1 = (void *) 0xfffffffffffffec0
```

The %fs segment is loaded in `__libc_setup_tls` via syscall `arch_prct` (as I learned in another thread) and there seem to be a loop over program headers of type `PT_TLS` that probably determines the aggregated tls variable sizes that are marked via gcc's `__thread` keyword. The __thread marked variables seem to be accessed below the  `struct pthread` tcb using negative indexes.
The negative indexes of tls variables seems to be located in the global offset table, in the above example i.e.

```
 0x3542da(%rip) ... # 3ead78 <.got+0x18>
```

Question:
Is there a description on which elements (libc, ld, gcc) are involved in GOT tls indexes calculation and how it is done in detail? I guess that there is maybe a pre-calculated layout, but how are libraries handled that are loaded via libdl? etc...

Comment: This, https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf , provides you with a lot of details.

Comment: @nos: Thanks, this link is helpful.